# Действие с двусвязаным списком

Tags: c, двусвязный-список

Узел связного списка описан следующим кодом

```
struct list {
    int field;
    struct list* next;
    struct list* prev;
};
```

Выяснить, какое действие выполняет функция, представленная следующим фрагментом кода:

```
{
    struct list* prev, * next;
    prev = lst->prev;
    next = lst->next;
    if (prev != NULL)
    prev->next = lst->next;
    if (next != NULL)
    next->prev = lst->prev;
    free(lst);
    return(prev);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Удаление элемента `lst` из двунаправленного списка :)